# How do i unset :set -v from ghci?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I had some troubles earlier importing System.Random, and in the process of trying to fix this I did the command `:set -v` in the ghci terminal.

So now whenever I use `:r`, I get a lot of unnecessary information. So how do i unset the `:set -v` command?

Comment: Why not `:set -v0`, to set the verbosity to `0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the verbosity level to level *n* with `:set -vn`. If you write `-v`, this is short for `-v3`. The default verbosity level is `0`, so you can set the verbosity level back to `0` with:

```
:set -v0
```